# Update property in spring environment in java code

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application,
scenario: a property in application.properties is given. I want to update the property in the environment in the same application in java code.

Note: I do not want to use Spring config server, because I do not want to refresh the property manually.

I need a solution in which I could somehow, modify the properties set in the environment at runtime in java code.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
System.setProperty("key","value")
```

I believe at runtime you can use this to change the environment values.

Be careful with the placement of the above statement. `@Value` annotations will be evaluated by BeanPostProcessors during context initialization. You would surely get the updated system properties by autowiring `Environment` and use `environment.getProperty()`